# Any Suggestion about Free FTP Server for Testing

Tags: c#

I'm using FtpWebRequest to download files from FTP server.Am trying to test my code to connect FTP Server and download different size files. Is this any Free FTP server available ,so i can install in my local machine and connect thru FTPWebRequest to download the file.

I was trying FileZilla but it has some library problem,so i couldn't install the software.Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not just use the FTP server built into IIS?  It's free...

Comment: that's awesome Chris Lively, i never noticed that,can you please correct me,the FTP service inside IIS i can use it like FTP server ?

Comment: the FTP service inside of IIS *is* an FTP server.  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/263/installing-and-configuring-ftp-7-on-iis-7/

Comment: check this https://www.lifewire.com/windows-ftp-servers-free-817577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileZilla is very widely used, so I don't know what kind of problem you are having with it.  But you could alternatively use a python based server http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/

Comment: Thank TJD, it was throwing some Classlibrary.dll error,so i was trying again with Option "Full" it went thru. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[CompleteFTP Free](https://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/free) is a nice alternative to FileZilla Server, if I do say so myself (I'm one of the developers).  It has a similar feature-set and is also free.